# Convert '7-Apr-11' to DD-MM-YYYY in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to convert a date that has the month stored in 3 characters to a workable date format such as DD-MM-YYYY.  I have looked at the strftime() function and I can't find anything to work with this format.

Comment: strftime('%d-%m-%Y') should be equal to the format you're asking for

Comment: @caleb.breckon But this does not help with parsing the original dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn’t look as if SQLite was able to handle that format as a date natively. If you can only use SQLite (and can’t do a transformation of the data outside of it, e.g. in a scripting language processing the data), then you could go with nested `replace` calls, something like

```
replace(
  replace(
    replace(
      original_value,
      'Jan',
      '01'
    ),
    'Feb',
    '02'
  ),
  'Mar',
  '03'
)
```

etc., and ultimately make the year value a four-digit one using substring functionality.

Will probably not have the best performance, but for a one-time(?) data conversion it might be OK.

Answer (score 0):

For complete usage of date and time formatting, look at the
[documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually parse date.

In a single query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN d<9 THEN '0'||d ELSE d END||'-'||mmt.mm||'-'||CASE WHEN yy<80 THEN 2000+yy ELSE 1900+yy END FROM (
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(dt,1,s1-1) AS INTEGER) AS d, SUBSTR(dt,s1+1,s2-s1-1) AS mmm, CAST(SUBSTR(dt, s2+1) AS INTEGER) AS yy FROM (
        SELECT dt, s1, INSTR(SUBSTR(dt,s1+1),'-') + s1 AS s2 FROM (
            SELECT dt, INSTR(dt, '-') AS s1 FROM (
                SELECT '7-Apr-11' AS dt -- <<< Put your date here!
            )
        )
    )
) AS src LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT '01' AS mm, 'Jan' AS mmm
    UNION SELECT '02', 'Feb'
    UNION SELECT '03', 'Mar'
    UNION SELECT '04', 'Apr'
    UNION SELECT '05', 'May'
    UNION SELECT '06', 'Jun'
    UNION SELECT '07', 'Jul'
    UNION SELECT '08', 'Aug'
    UNION SELECT '09', 'Sep'
    UNION SELECT '10', 'Oct'
    UNION SELECT '11', 'Nov'
    UNION SELECT '12', 'Dec'
) AS mmt ON src.mmm=mmt.mmm;
```

Y2K: This will assume year<80 as 20xx, else 19xx.