# I need a sqlite equivalent of the folling msaccess query

Tags: sqlite, dateadd

Select distinct Format(DateAdd(""s""," & columnname & ",""1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM""), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') as A

Comment: So just to confirm the requirements, you want to be able to add a number of seconds to a fixed date and time. The number of seconds is contained in 'columnname' in your query above? Is this a parameter or a column from a table, the name suggests the later, but you are not selecting from a table.

Comment: Also, from the formatting it looks like you want to add an amount in seconds, but the truncate the result to just the date. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for youe response.The column name is fetched from a table wherin it contains date.Select distinct Format(DateAdd("s",EXPIRY_DATE,"1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM"), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') as A .its like getting the seconds from unixdate however rather than unix date i have to use 1/1/1980 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you provide a full example in the question for the value in Expiry Date and the result of the query please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that the seconds to add and the original date are hard coded values below whilst awaiting clarifications requested in the comments.

To add a number of seconds to a date you can use:

```
select datetime('1980-01-01 00:00:00', "345000 seconds");
```

This gives the result: `1980-01-04 23:50:00`

The example above is just under 4 days in seconds, if you want to truncate the result to just the date as implied by the query in your questions then you can wrap this inside a date function. However, this would give the result in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" rather than "DD-MMM-YYYY" as your access query does.

Unfortunately I cannot find any native SQLite function to convert a numeric month value to mmm format. You can do this manually with replace (similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283759/convert-7-apr-11-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-sqlite)), but this is a bit messy.

If you are happy to live with the numeric months then you can simply use:

```
select strftime('%d-%m-%Y', '1980-01-01 00:00:00', "345000 seconds");
```

This gives the result: `04-01-1980`

More information on the SQLite date / time functions can be found [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).